# How is noise analysis done in practice

Tags: communication, dsp, signal-theory

If we identify a signal as a Random Process how do we study it in practice, how to determine its characteristics such as stationarity(whether it is Stationary, Wide Sense Stationary or ergodic),how to find the autocorrelation function of a brand new signal.

When I referred my communications textbook it only talks about these characteristics in a mathematical way, and these characteristics are always mentioned in problem solving. Basically how is noise analysis done in real life

Answer (score 0):

I must have missed that [class](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1167/what-is-the-distinction-between-ergodic-and-stationary) many decades ago.

Real-world noise such as acoustic noise or electromagnetic interference EMI comes in many time and spectral shapes: Impulse, random thermal noise, adjacent channel, logic impulse crosstalk, Intersymbol Interference (ISI), Harmonic, random white noise, pink noise, brown noise, noise for SNR vs BER plots and random data for auto-correlation analysis for the sync word that is single bit error tolerant.

White noise can be a thermal noise from a Zener diode or a random number generator such as cheap PSRG IC's using counters and XOR gates or very expensive microwave white noise generators.

More examples could fill a thumb drive.

Noise meters vary in cost from a few dollars to 100k$ depend on accuracy of measurement and bandwidth to display the spectral density value in dBm or dBA for example.

This [professor](https://youtu.be/k6y2kzayV6A?list=UUZCDx4cxOF3Bd57k3ek-YpQ&t=1368) explains an ergodic process of randomness as a repeating noise or in other words, a Pseudo Random Process.

- i.e. Future segments of randomness are indistinguishable from a present sample means ERGODIC.